# Getting Exception trying to add a field in the form using devise (customize devise)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to to add a field first name in my form ,I have changed in the view template,user model,updated the table(*rails g add_firstname_to user firstname:string migration*).But i am still getting an exception undefined method `firstname' for #. what am i missing ?my file looks like this

view

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do   |f|     %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
<table>
  <tr><td><label>First name</label></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :firstname %></td></tr>


  <tr><td><label>Email</label></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :email %></td></tr>

   <tr><td><%= f.label :password %></td>
<td><%= f.password_field :password %></td></tr>

<tr><td><%= f.label :password_confirmation %></td>
<td><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></td></tr>

</table>
<p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

User model class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:firstname
end
```

Comment: This may be silly, but did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **step by step [tutorial](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/rails-%E2%80%93-add-custom-fields-to-devise-user-model/)** will tell you everything. :)

Looking at your code, two suggestions:

- You said you runned `rails g add_firstname_to user firstname:string migration`
  I hope this is a typo in here, but you should use `add_firstname_to_users` - Notice the **s** on user.
- As the first comment suggests, did you run `rake db:migrate` ?